# AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'startEditing'

Tags: pyqgis

**Good morning, I'm new to pyqgis.
I'm trying to create a new field in my attribute table but it's not working if someone can help me I appreciate it
follow the code:**

```
    # Calculadora de campo
    alg_params = {
        'FIELD_LENGTH': 0,
        'FIELD_NAME': 'campo1',
        'FIELD_PRECISION': 0,
        'FIELD_TYPE': 1,  # Número inteiro
        'FORMULA': ' $id ',
        'INPUT': parameters['entrecomacamada'],
        'OUTPUT': parameters['Saida']
    }
    outputs = processing.run('native:fieldcalculator', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)
    results['Saida'] = outputs
    
    **results.startEditing()
    results.addAttribute(QgsFiel('campo1'),QVariant.String)
    results.commitChanges()**
    
    
    return results
```

Comment: Can you add the full error message to the answer? The full stack trace.

Comment: And what is `results`? Where do you declare it?

Comment: so...it keeps giving error....got this error

TypeError: QgsVectorLayer(): argument 1 has unexpected type 'dict'

I don't even know how to fix it anymore...

Comment: ,ou can't really be helped unless you provide more detail.